Drawing celestial equator, ecliptic, and galactic equator on a stereographic star chart
Given a star map (stereographic projection), suppose I have identified the pole star, latitude, and one zodiac constellation. After that, how do I precisely draw upon the map the celestial equator, the ecliptic, and the galactic equator (maybe some other information is needed for this)? What will be the shapes of these structures?

You just need to loop through the galactic/ecliptic/RA,Dec coordinates where lat=0 and lon = 0...360, and convert those into the coordinates on the projection.  E.g. for the graphic at the link below, the projection is RA/Dec, so I looped through 0...360 for the ecliptic coordinates, converted those to RA/Dec coordinates, then projected those onto the plane. https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6735561 . Here is the code https://gist.github.com/gmiller123456/ccb42dc8f13b81611b9f76cf0d66b906
